# Как происходит блокировка синхронной функции, выполняющей сетевой запрос?

Tags: c++, linux, c, сеть, асинхронность

С асинхронными всё понятно: `event loop` с `thread pool`'ом, и вызов `callback`'а по событию через добавление в очередь. Но как происходит блокировка? Если функция вызвана, она должна на каком-то моменте остановиться, и зациклится на проверке результата. Это же не через бесконечный цикл реализуется? Или да?

```cpp
while (true) {
    if (atomic_completed) break;
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(10ms);
}
```

**Это единственный способ блокирующего вызова?** (*мне кажется, что это костыль*)

**PS#1:** Понятно что у ядра ОС своя внутрення очередь, но это ж другой процесс, а текущий как останавливается?

**PS#2:** Видимо у API ОС должна быть функция типа: *останови мой поток, пока сетевой запрос не вернёт ответ*?

Comment: Да, и называется это event, на русском событие, или condition variable, или mutex, реализаций множество, однако все для чего-то одного используются. Однако следует учесть что не все из перечисленных поддерживаются на уровне платформ. И реализованы в основном, на уровне ОС.

Comment: @ori, да какие мьютексы или семафоры между процессами?

Comment: Это вопрос про то, как реализовано в ядре?

Comment: @avp, ну да, про API ОС, в конце концов, все библиотеки используют API ОС.

Comment: Прежде всего надо понимать, что ядро это не отдельный процесс, а скорее библиотека, манипулирующая разделяемыми между всеми процессами данными. Т.е. системный вызов recv будет исполняться в том же процессе, который его вызвал. Если данных в очереди сокета нет, то он поставит сам себя в очередь, связанную с событиями на сокете (т.е. занесет свой tcb (task control block)) в эту очередь, выставит признак ожидания события в tcb и вызовет функцию планировщика (scheduler), который найдет для данного ядра какой-нибудь из ожидающих cpu процессов и переключится на него.